# How to create a list of variables using a for loop in R

Tags: r, list, loops

I have a list of 100 variables lets say v1 to v100.
I want to create a list that holds each of these variable in a seprate column. What i have done is

```
s=list()
for (i in 1:100){
  name=paste("v",i,sep="")
  s[name]=vi
```

}

Now the problem is how to make R treat vi as name for the variable that will be stored in list. On running the above written code the console is showing the error

```
Error in s[name] = vi : 
`cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'list'
```

Comment: You say that you have a list of 100 variables, so the variables are already in a list or? Where are currently stored your variables? Do you have really 100 different variables v1=x; v2=y; v3=z and so on?

Comment: `s[[i]]=vi` instead of `s[name]=vi` ... probably this is what you are looking for. In any case the error you get is because of using `s[name]`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `mget` to create a list based on multiple objects.

Here's an example:

```
v1 <- 1:3
v2 <- 4:6

mget(paste0("v", 1:2))
# $v1
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# $v2
# [1] 4 5 6
```

The correct names are assigned automatically.

Comment: Or if you want to get all of the at once without specifying indexes `mget(ls(pattern = "^v[0-9]$"))`

Comment: cool, +1 for mget. Though it'd be more reproducible if we'd create the list of 100 elements which the OP claims to have...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's try to make things reproducible first.

```
# I generate a list of 100 random normal vector with 50 elements
s <- list()
for(i in 1:100) s[[i]] <- rnorm(50)

# Creating the names vector(!) does not need any loops. 
nms <- paste("v",1:100,sep="")

# if you already have the list like you say, you're done.
names(s) <- nms
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your variables v1, v2, v3, etc. you can use:

```
s=list()
for (i in 1:100){
  name=paste("v",i,sep="")
  s[[name]]=get(name) #write to the list with [[ ]] operator
}
```

The get function returns the value of the variable with the name equal to the string passed as argument (if the variable exists).

Please note that this will copy the value, and it does not create a reference to that variables, as usual in R. So if you then change the value of a variable it does not also change in the list (and viceversa).